# What sort of API are best suite for online website database to comminucate with mobile application

Tags: c#, android, ios, json

We have a web site which has been developed in ASP.Net webform framework 4.0 / C# and runs on IIS 7x web server

We now are in a need for a mobile application that can perform CRUD operation and communicate with MS SERVER database using `Webservices` or API.

Since I don't have experience in Mobile application I would like to know what sort of API would be the best approach?

We need application for both iOS and Android mobile platforms.

Taken into consideration I data is stored in ms server has following field structure:

TABLE NEWS

```
News_ID       int
News_Title    nvarchar(100)
News_Brief    nvarchar(500)
News_Details  nvarchar(MAX)
News_Date     DateTime
News_Image    varchar(100)
```

This is a simple structure where `News_Details` field stores new details in rich HTML.

Besides this we have contact us form which also need to be saved in database using these API.

I would appreciate what parameters I should take in to consideration while deciding on type of API to use like `REST`, `JSON` or XML based based web services.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack):

Service Stack is a high-performance .NET web services platform that simplifies the development of high-performance REST (JSON, XML, JSV, HTML, MsgPack, ProtoBuf, CSV) and WCF SOAP Web Services.